# Identityserver unauthorized_client error in implicit flow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

My Identity Server works well in some weeks after that I have gotten an unauthorized_client error, I don't know why.

Identity Server host in http://localhost:5001

Angular Started with .Net Core project in http://localhost:4200

The exact error is:

> Sorry, there was an error: unauthorized_client
>
> Unknown client or client not enabled

In the Identity Server, my client defined as follow:

```
var clients = new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "app.spa.client",
                ClientName = "Client Application",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false,

                RedirectUris =
                    {
                        "http://localhost:4200/assets/oidc-login-redirect.html",
                        "http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-redirect.html"
                    },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:4200/?postLogout=true" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new[] { "http://localhost:4200/" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "webapi"
                },
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 120,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 120
            }
        };
```

And in Angular project, I'm using from *oidc-client* and my config is like follow:

```
var config = {
            authority: "http://localhost:5001/",
            client_id: "app.spa.client",
            redirect_uri: `http://localhost:4200/assets/oidc-login-redirect.html`,
            scope: "openid profile webapi",
            response_type: "id_token token",
            post_logout_redirect_uri: `http://localhost:4200/?postLogout=true`,
            userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            silent_redirect_uri: `http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-redirect.html`
        };
```

Have you ever been this error?

How I can find more details of this error?

Comment: Can you provide the log output from your identityserver4 service please?

Comment: @mackie Thanks, Eventually, I found the problem, IdentityServer4 package was updated to version 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the problem, The IdentityServer4 package in Identity service updated from version 2.4.0 to 2.5.0 but I can't resolve this problem.

Eventually, I'm forced to be down-grade to 2.4.0 version and my problem solved.

Any Idea to solve this problem in IdentityServer4 version 2.5.0?